# screenplay-pkg not working with memoir.cls

Tags: memoir, screenplay

Trying to use `screenplay-pkg.sty` with `memoir` document class.
This gives the error-message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@screenspacing ->\onehalfspacing
```

but using document class "book" compiles correct.

Any ideas??
MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{screenplay-pkg}
%===================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{screenplay}
\fadein
\intslug{office}

X entering the room.

\begin{dialogue}{X}
  Blah..
\end{dialogue}
\end{screenplay}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the `\EmulatePackage` feature of the `memoir` class. It emulates the `setspace` package and seems to disable some stuff thereby.
This feature can be switched off using `\DisemulatePackage{setspace}`.

The reason, why it works with `book` class is that `screenplay-pkg` loads `setspace` already.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\documentclass{book}
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{screenplay-pkg}
%===================================================
\begin{document}
\begin{screenplay}
\fadein
\intslug{office}

X entering the room.

\begin{dialogue}{X}
  Blah..
\end{dialogue}
\end{screenplay}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `screenplay-pkg` package (as of v1.1) now checks for `memoir` and uses its spacing commands, if the class is loaded,  so `\DisemulatePackage` should no longer be used.